# Splitting page with lines

Tags: margins, line, box

I'm trying to do two things and I feel like I'm using wrong tools for both of these things... :)

1. I need a line exactly at top margin, the next paragraph should start below as it would normally
2. I want to split page in two sections and draw line between them. Line should be placed at 50% between top margin and bottom of the page.

What I got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,top=1cm,left=1cm, right=1cm, bottom=0cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{calc}
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\raisebox{0.5cm}{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}}
\Large{test test test test test test test test test test test test}


\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(1cm,0.5\textheight+1cm)
   \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
\Large{test test test test test test test test test test test test}
\end{textblock*}

    
\end{document}
```

Issue with that is:

- I had to use `\raisebox{0.5cm}` to actually match line to margin - I would assume because `\makebox` is creating box for text and the line is aligned as text would be?
- There is pretty big spacing below the line (basically like for a paragraph of text).
- Bottom half is actually spaced correctly, but have doubts if `\textblock` is the best tool to achieve that.

How can I improve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the text in two separate `\parbox`es of equal half-textblock sizes and add the horizontal rules as an overlay at exactly the right position (using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{\hspace*{-1cm}\rule{\paperwidth}{.4pt}}% Bottom line
  \AtTextLowerLeft{\hspace*{-1cm}\rule[.5\textheight]{\paperwidth}{.4pt}}% Center line
  \AtTextUpperLeft{\hspace*{-1cm}\rule{\paperwidth}{.4pt}}% Top line
}

\noindent\parbox[t][.5\textheight]{\textwidth}{%
  \Large\raggedright\strut\lipsum*[1]\strut
}

\noindent\parbox[t][.5\textheight]{\textwidth}{%
  \Large\raggedright\strut\lipsum*[2]\strut
}

\end{document}
```